# Mint ERC721 token to specific account

Tags: nft, erc721

How can I mint an NFT using ERC 721 directly to someone's wallet? I have done IPFS pinning for my NFT and am using truffle console to mint. I am able to mint the tokens but they are from my wallet only. I need it to be minted in the name of metamask logged user. Can someone help?

Comment: how did you write minftfunction in contract

Comment: function claimItem(string memory tokenURI) public returns (uint256) {
        _tokenIds.increment();
        uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();

        _safeMint(msg.sender, newItemId);
//        _safeMint(to, newItemId);
        _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);
        return newItemId;
    }

Answer (score 0):

To mint to a certain user, you'd have to add a parameter to your mint function.

```
function mint(address _to, ...) public payable {
    // ...
    _safeMint(_to, ...);
}
```

Something like this. And then in your dApp you'd simply add the connected wallet's address as the `_to` parameter.